# Can't join two tables in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, select, join

i have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE "object_comment" 
("object_id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL, 
"object_comment_text" TEXT, 
"object_comment_title" TEXT, 
"object_comment_date" DATETIME)
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE "object_comment_mark" 
("object_id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  DEFAULT null, 
"object_comment_mark_value" FLOAT DEFAULT null, 
"object_comment_mark_date" DATETIME DEFAULT null)
```

I need to join them with the object_id field but the unique rows should present in results too. (there are some equal object_id values which I need to join in one row and some object_id values are different but they should be in the result table)

Now I have this select query:

```
SELECT *
FROM object_comment
LEFT OUTER JOIN object_comment_mark ON object_comment.object_id = object_comment_mark.object_id
```

But in this case I don't have the rows from the second table where the object_id has unique value. Any help?

EDIT: what I need

object_comment

```
1 | bla-bla | first | 2013
2 | be-be   | sec   | 2014
```

object_comment_mark

```
1 | 5 | 2013
4 | 3 | 2013
```

result

```
1 |bla-bla | first| 2013 | 5 | 2013
2 | be-be  | sec  | 2014 |   |     
4 |        |      |      | 3 | 2013
```

Comment: Is the `object_id` of the 2nd table the `foreign key`? Because you mentioned it is not unique. On a `one-to-many` relationship the many side always has the `foreign key`.

Comment: The object_id keys in this twi tables are unique. But they may be different. I need to show all the rows from this two tables but join the rows with the same object_id.

Comment: So, how could you join the two tables when they have both unique `object_id`? Are records in `object_comment_mark` created when a record is created in `object_comment`? And if that's the case does it mean you have to create only one record only for each or one or more records for each?

Comment: See the edit in my question

Comment: you will never get such a result...result will not contain more than max number of rows than either of table

Comment: This is like a pivot table with outer join. I think you have to revisit your original database design instead on this one. If the cardinality between this two tables is one-to-one then it would be much better to make it as one table. And your query would be very simple compared to the very complex that you want to do now because of poor design.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is full outer join, which is not supported by SQLite.
Instead, you could combine a left join and the unmatched (NULL) records of a right join.
A right join isn't supported either, so use a left join with the two tables swapped:

```
SELECT oc.*, ocm.*
FROM object_comment AS oc
LEFT JOIN object_comment_mark AS ocm ON oc.object_id = ocm.object_id
UNION ALL
SELECT oc.*, ocm.*
FROM object_comment_mark AS ocm
LEFT JOIN object_comment AS oc       ON oc.object_id = ocm.object_id
WHERE oc.object_id IS NULL
```

Alternatively, search for unmatched records by hand:

```
SELECT oc.*, ocm.*
FROM object_comment AS oc
LEFT JOIN object_comment_mark AS ocm ON oc.object_id = ocm.object_id
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, *
FROM object_comment_mark
WHERE object_id NOT IN (SELECT object_id
                        FROM object_comment)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not understanding exactly your question...

Is this you need?

```
SELECT * FROM object_comment
INNER JOIN object_comment_mark ON object_comment.object_id = object_comment_mark.object_id
UNION ALL
SELECT *, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL FROM object_comment
```

Comment: Sorry EN is not my native language. First of all in your case u have 1 extra NULL in second select. But the result is wrong all in all. To say it simpler I need to count the quantity of the distinct object_id fields in both tables first of all. Than I need a table object_id | all the columns from both tables. object_id will be unique in this table.